# Opentok api use in android

Tags: android

I want to use OpenTok API for android.
I found example on github. and causes some exceptions like.
1.my video is not publishing.
2.I receive the stream but unable to get view.
3.pulisher.create(); cause exception.

Is this is only for jellybean os. how to implement it for lower version.
I am using it on my nexus s jellybean updated.

Any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is OpenTok's Android repository. According to their readme, The supported devices are:

Nexus 4
Nexus 7
Nexus 10
Galaxy S3

Requirements for OS is Jelly Bean and up.

Live video streaming is CPU intensive, and lower end devices do not have the CPU capacity to handle multiple video processing for the streams in the session and not able to run OpenTok's SDK.